# Live Server Extension gets stuck iterating through port values every time I "Open with live server" from my html file

Tags: html, liveserver

My file name is index.html
I have tried running the command and manually entering http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html into the browser this also does not work. I get a refused to connect message.
I have ensured I have a default browser set.
I have tried just about everything.

As soon as I select "Open with live server" VS Code starts processing the request, I navigate to settings.json where the extensions settings reside.
All I have in my settings.json is

"liveserver.settings.port": 5500

and in real time the file starts increasing the port number by 1 about every second. I have to physically close VS Code to stop it. "Stop live server" does not work.

I have tried uninstalling the extension, older versions, and even completely uninstalling VS Code.
NOTHING is working.
Please send help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the steps from this question:
[Live server installed but not working in VS code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62241170/live-server-installed-but-not-working-in-vs-code)

Comment: This thread does not solve the problem.